# Mounting my TimeCapsule on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mount, samba, cifs

I am newbie to mounting, but already used ubuntu on a user level. I have installed Ubuntu with an XBMC and wanted to mount my timecapsule as well so I can manipulate the data on it. What I tried until now to mount it (from google & internet) using

`sudo mkdir /mnt/TC`

and

`sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.13/Data/ /mnt/TC -o User=htpc Pass=XXXXXX`

I also tried to add `sec=ntlm`, that didn't work.

I am getting an error(22) here and even going through the manpages, I wasn't enlighted.
Strangely enough the access from XBMC workings fine on the SMB share...

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

This is coming rather late, but I believe options are comma separated. Try

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.13/Data /mnt/TC -o user=htpc,pass=xxxx,sec=ntlm
```

with lower case and the comma.

Note:

- In `sudo mount.cifs //192.168.0.13/Data`, use `Data` or the name you've given to your timecapsule. This depends on whether you've activated the separation between disk and users.
- If you've used characters like `!` or `^` in your password, then you'll need to put the whole option within quotes, like so: `-o 'user=htpc,pass=xxxx,sec=ntlm'`
- Use `sec=ntlm` or `sec=ntlmv2` depending of your version of timecapsule